# Spring threads in web app

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc

I am writing server for MMO browser game, and I need to make few threads.
They will be running all the time with some sleep time. 
Is it good idea, to use spring threads like this?

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class PrintTask2 implements Runnable{

String name;

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    System.out.println(name + " is running");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(name + " is running");

}
```

}

with task executor implemented as bean?

```
<bean id="taskExecutor"
       class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Also, threads are started in singleton also defined as a bean.

What can be wrong in my approach?

Comment: Did you solve your issue? Just ask if you need more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)` to execute a method periodic. Remember to set `@EnableScheduling` for class containing your main method.

There are two options for the `@Scheduled` annotation - `fixedDelay`and `fixedRate`.

`fixedDelay` will continuously execute your method with a delay of X miliseconds after the last execution has finished.

`fixedRate` will continuously execute your method with at a fixed date. So every X milisecond this method will be executed regardless if the last execution has finished.

You can also use `@Async` if you want to process a bunch of objects all at once. Once again, you need to add `@EnableAsync` to your class with your main method.

**Example**

```
//Remember to set @EnableScheduling
//in the class containing your main method
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}

@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

List<YourObject> myObjects;

    //This method will run every 5 second.
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void yourMethodName() {
        //This will process all of your objects all at once using treads
        for(YourObject yo : myObjects){
            yo.process();
        }
    }
}

public class YourObject {

    Integer someTest = 0;

    @Async
    public void process() {
       someTest++;
    }
}
```

**Bonus**
You can get rid of your XML configuration for the pool size by extending `AsyncConfigurerSupport` and override `getAsyncExecutor`. More information about this approach can be found at the below links

I suggest that you take a look at:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Comment: So then I don't really create Threads? Sounds nice. When I don't have main method(I'm not using SpringBoot) should I add @EnableAsync annotation in singleton, which is starting this threads?

Comment: Ok, I found it. If someone will be looking for similar thing: it can be made by putting <task:annotation-driven> in XML

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Async in case you want to invoke a single thread programmatically (e.g. you want to send 50 mail and you send them creating 50 different thread, each one to send a single message, then wait until all threads end), or @Scheduled to let a method / thread run at fixed rate (or after some time from previous execution end).

You can put an eye on https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support for further details.

```
@Service
public class MyAsyncStuff {
    @Async
    public Future<String> callMe(String param) {  
       // do your work here...         
       return new AsyncResult<String>("Sent: "+param);           
    }
}

@Service 
public class MyWorker {
    @Inject
    MyAsyncStuff stuff;

    public void invoker() {
        List<Future<String>> futures = new Arraylist<>();
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
           futures.add(stuff.callMe("Invoked "+i));
        }
        for (Future<String> fut : futures) {
           try {
              System.out.println(futures.get();
           } catch (Exception e) {
             // Spock? Do something!
           }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Ok, so if I want single thread doing all the work and not starting different ones, I should use @Scheduled? And what about starting them in singleton?

Comment: It depends on what you want to accomplish. Do you have a collection of objects that you wish to process all at once, then you need to use @Async. If you however want to perform a specific task periodically, then you want to use `@scheduled`. You can also combine the two annotations, to perform a task periodically which processes a collection of objects all at once.

Comment: (at)Scheduled is used to exec a task repeatdly, e.g. if you want to check for something at some time interval. You can't stop or start is when you want. If you want to start a thread to let it make something in background, in order to not block execution (e.g. to prepare a zip file then send it via mail when complete) a (at)Async is what you need. A PrintTask probably falls in this 2nd case.